# Using webpack to optimise unreferenced images (img-loader)

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to transition from gulp to webpack and I'm trying to optimise my images. I've found img-loader to be the most widely used and while this works great for images referenced in the CSS or html files I'm not referencing some images directly but still need them to be optimised and moved to the dist folder.

I've been looking into ways of doing this but I can't find any examples that cover just the optimisation, most seem to be focused on built static pages where as I'm using this in a WordPress theme.

Ideally I just wan to run the image optimisation on the entire directory and save them into dist

Currently I have the following

```
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                outputPath: 'images',
            },
        },
        'img-loader'
    ]
}
```

Comment: webpack only runs through things that are referenced on your code somehow, starting from your entry points. That would be a job for gulp or any other task runner, webpack is not really a substitute for that!

Comment: It's mainly to not have multiple processes running at once and be able to have a single instance of browsersync running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like @PlayMa256 said, webpack is a bundler & not really a replacement for gulp!
However, you can kinda force webpack to do what you want, by combining [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) with a optimizer like [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp)

Perhaps something like this

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const sharp = require('sharp');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: 'src/images/*.png',
        to: 'images',
        flatten: true,
        transform: content => sharp(content).resize(300).toBuffer(),
      },
    ])
  ]
}
```

Or checkout [imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin) if you'd want to use the same optimizer that `img-loader` use, you can probably pass the same option to both as well.